# session variables in case of url redirections

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat, servlets

I have a application running on tomcat server , which is redirected to another website for password authentication ( and store some data) , and then redirected back to my tomcat server

EX

1 to A
A to B
B to 2

Where 1 and 2 are pages on my application
A and B are pages on other applications

I am setting a session variable on my page 1 using

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("loginUser", "loginUser");
```

and using it on page 2 using

```
String loginUser= session.getAttribute("loginUser");
```

but getting a null pointer exception on 2

Comment: SSO, single sign-on, is a more complex topic, where you have to read. Passing the sessionid to the other site is not such a good idea, JSESSIONID=... is however available (originally for non-JavaScript browsers). OpenID is a totally other way of SSO, one which I like.

Comment: Is 1 the page where the session is created? Are cookies enabled? What's time between 1 to A and B to 2?

Comment: Check out the SSO solutions (www.jasig.org CAS in one example). If you want to do it your self you may try using cookies instead of session variables though wouldn't be as good as using an SSO...

Comment: @JBNizet: session is created at 1 ? i did not do any thing to cookies . transmit between pages is continues

Comment: Session management based on cookies or URL rewriting?

Comment: Maybe your browser does not accept cookies on response with the 302 code. Check if cookies are set, if the browser accepts them, and if it sends them with the B to 2 request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a redirect in the same context (Application), rather use `RequestDispatcher` to do a `forward` (passing your `request` and `response`). That way, you pass your session through.

Otherwise, my suggestion is to not store the `loginUser` on the session but pass user id variable as some intelligent (and confused) string to the other application, write a mechanism to retrieve the user logged in session state and carry on from there. This is called, Single-Sign On.

Comment: can you suggest me a mechanism to retrive user sesssion state

Answer (score 0):

it may be happening because of

'A session is transient, and its lifetime ends when one of the following occurs:

```
A user leaves your site and the user's browser does not accept cookies.

A user quits the browser.

The session is timed out due to inactivity.

The session is completed and invalidated by the servlet.

The user logs out and is invalidated by the servlet.'
```

refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13712/sessions.htm